# Prove that the series $\sum^{\infty}_{n=1} n^{\alpha}(\sqrt[n]{3} - 1)$ is convergent if and only if $a < 0$.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I am trying to prove that  $\sum^{\infty}_{n=1} n^{\alpha}(\sqrt[n]{3} - 1)$  is convergent if and only if $a < 0$ for some time now, but so far I did not come up with anything smart. Would you mind suggesting some hint how should I approach this exercise? I was trying to use comparison test but could not find any good candidates.

Comment: $0<\sqrt[n]{3}-1<1$ for all $n$ large enough. you can thus use a comparison type of criteria.

Comment: Hint: Find bounds for $\sqrt[n]3-1.$

Comment: Being less than $1$ only gives $\alpha<-1.$ though @OliverDiaz

Comment: thanks! I am gonna try it after the quick walk, seems like a good approach

Comment: @ThomasAndrews: Then one can get a slightly better bound using Bernoulli's inequality.

Comment: I know how to solve it, just pointing out your comment was far from sufficient. For $a<-1,$ you just need $\sqrt[n]3-1$ is bounded, which it clearly is. @OliverDiaz

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**HINT**

Start with noticing that

\begin{align*}
\sqrt[n]{3} - 1 & = \frac{(\sqrt[n]{3} - 1)(\sqrt[n]{3^{n-1}} + \sqrt[n]{3^{n-2}} + \ldots + \sqrt[n]{3} + 1)}{\sqrt[n]{3^{n-1}} + \sqrt[n]{3^{n-2}} + \ldots + \sqrt[n]{3} + 1}\\\\
& = \frac{2}{\sqrt[n]{3^{n-1}} + \sqrt[n]{3^{n-2}} + \ldots + \sqrt[n]{3} + 1} < \frac{2}{n}
\end{align*}

Consequently, the following relation holds:
\begin{align*}
n^{\alpha}(\sqrt[n]{3} - 1) < \frac{2n^{\alpha}}{n} = \frac{2}{n^{1 - \alpha}}
\end{align*}

Now it remains the question: when the series corresponding to the last general term converges?

Can you take it from here?

Comment: Yes thanks, cool trick, but I have a trouble understanding how the numerator equals 2. Could you clarify it a bit?

Comment: Yes, sure. I have applied the following identity:

$$a^{n} - b^{n} = (a - b)(a^{n-1} + a^{n-2}b + a^{n-3}b^{2} + \ldots + ab^{n-2} + b^{n-1})$$

At the given example, $a = \sqrt[n]{3}$ and $b = 1$.

Comment: Thanks, I got it now!

Comment: @BartekSzmelczynski You are welcome ! I am glad I could help.

Answer (score 1):

As a hint note that if $f(t) = t^{1/n}$ then $$3^{1/n} - 1 = f(3) - f(1) = \int_1^3 f'(t) = \frac 1n \int_1^3 t^{1/n-1} \, dt$$ where
$$\frac {\ln 3}n < \frac 1n \int_1^3 t^{1/n-1} \, dt < \frac 2n.$$

Comment: You don't need integrals. If $y=\sqrt[n]3-1,$ then $1+ny\leq (1+y)^n=3,$ given $y\leq \frac2n.$ And $3^{1/n}=e^{\ln 3/n}>1+\frac{\ln 3}n.$

Answer (score 1):

More generally, if $a>-1$ let $y_n=\sqrt[n]a-1.$

Then, since $y_n>-1,$ by Bernoulli, $$1+ny_n\leq (1+y_n)^n=a$$ so $y_n\leq\frac{a-1}n.$

Also, $$a^{1/n}=e^{\log a/n}\geq 1+\frac{\log a}{n},$$ by the rule $e^x\geq 1+x.$ So  $y_n\geq\frac{\log a}{n}.$

Also, $a-1$ and $\log a$ have the same sign, so we have $y_n$ strictly bound.

Answer (score 1):

For $\alpha>0$ the posted solutions solve the necessity of the statement in the OP. It remains to see what happens when $\alpha\geq0$. We may the mean value theorem to show that
$$3^{1/n}-1=\log(3)3^{\theta_n/n}\frac{1}{n}$$
where $0<\theta_n<\frac1n$. Hence
$n^\alpha(\sqrt[n]{3}-1)\geq \log(3)\frac{1}{n^{1-\alpha}}$ and so, divergence follows for $\alpha\geq0$.